# running ghostscript on jenkins doesnt display ps file

Tags: jenkins, terminal, ghostscript, jenkins-pipeline, rhel

I am running ghostscript with the following command on a .ps (pdf) file to display it on terminal :

```
gs -sDEVICE=display -dNOPAUSE graph.ps
```

where graph.gs is the ps file containing a graph and gs = ghostscript (https://ghostscript.com/) . I am newbie on ghostscript so ignore any stupidity. 
When I run the job on jenkins I get the following :

```
GS>+ gs -sDEVICE=display -dNOPAUSE graph.ps
GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/NimbusRomNo9L-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusRomNo9L-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/NimbusRomNo9L-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusRomNo9L-Regu.
Querying operating system for font files...
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-Regu font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n021003l.pfb... 3508768 2086694 2448692 1153761 2 done.
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n021023l.pfb... 3552240 2216374 2670716 1352857 2 done.
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-Medi font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n021004l.pfb... 3699560 2367722 2670716 1358308 2 done.
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-MediItal font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n021024l.pfb... 3843664 2501778 2670716 1363735 2 done.
Loading NimbusSanL-Regu font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n019003l.pfb... 3967136 2627944 2670716 1369394 2 done.
Loading NimbusSanL-ReguItal font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n019023l.pfb... 4087536 2738966 2670716 1374709 2 done.
Loading NimbusSanL-Bold font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n019004l.pfb... 4189080 2849279 2690900 1383454 2 done.
Loading NimbusSanL-BoldItal font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n019024l.pfb... 4309544 2961260 2690900 1388681 2 done.
Loading NimbusMonL-Regu font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n022003l.pfb... 4453408 2977287 2659800 1099632 2 done.
Loading NimbusMonL-ReguObli font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n022023l.pfb... 4513832 3098942 2659800 1105017 2 done.
Loading NimbusMonL-Bold font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n022004l.pfb... 4677928 3250154 2659800 1110244 2 done.
Loading NimbusMonL-BoldObli font from /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n022024l.pfb... 4817392 3385828 2659800 1115471 2 done.
```

This doesn't print the ps file image on jenkins console output(stdout). What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The display device doesn't print to the console, it sends it to an X11 window (on Unix, on Windows its a window).

Given that Ghostscript renders complex graphics to a bitmap, what were you expecting to see on the console output ?

Comment: I have a simple graph created by terraform which I create using graphviz : terraform graph > graph.dot; dot -Tps graph.dot -o graph.ps which I want to display on console. IS there any tool to do it if not ghostscript ?

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what it is you are asking for. Did you want an ASCII art representation of the graphic ? The binary data from a bitmap image (eg PNG) ? Something else ? Possibly I don't understand your use of 'console', perhaps Jenkins has something other than a simple terminal for a console. For a terminal window you can't 'display' rendered output, that's like asking how to display a photograph of your dog on the console.

Comment: OK well you can't get Ghostscript to do that.